# How to calculate size of a codebook lookup table to break block cipher?

Tags: encryption, aes, des

I was reading a book called Serious Cryptography. There is a page saying that block size must be large enough to prevent codebook attacks:

> When 16-bit blocks are used, the lookup table needs only 2^16 × 16 = 2^20 bits
> of memory, or 128 kilobytes. With 32-bit blocks, memory needs
> grow to 16 gigabytes, which is still manageable. But with 64-bit
> blocks, you’d have to store 2 70 bits (a zetabit, or 128 exabytes), so
> forget about it. Codebook attacks won’t be an issue for larger blocks.

Where is the `2^16 * 16` coming from? I think it's supposed to be `2^16 + 2^16` the sum of ciphertext possibilities and the sum of plaintext possibilities that match this specific ciphertext, right?

Comment: https://sweet32.info/

Comment: after $2^{n/2}$ message blocks encrypted with the same key (in the same message or in different messages), a collision between two ciphertext blocks $c_i = c_j$ is expected. Take $n=64$ then $2^{32}$ by birthday paradox. And, With $2^d$ blocks of data the expected number of collisions is roughly $2^{2d-n-1}$ (following the birthday paradox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where is $2^{16}\cdot16$ bits coming from?

The $2^{16}$ term is the number of possible 16-bit blocks. The $16$ bit term is the space needed to store a block (that can be a block of ciphertext, with the plaintext used as index; or vice versa). The two are multiplied to get the total size, much like the price for $n$ things is $n$ times the price for one thing.

If we added the number of plaintexts and ciphertexts blocks, we'd get a number of blocks, not a size. And while we need to be able to manipulate all the plaintexts and all the ciphertexts, we do not need space to *store* both all the plaintexts and all the ciphertexts: one kind comes for free as the index of the table, which uses no space. Much like if we want to store what output from `0` to `9` correspond to input `0` to `9`, we need 10 digits (like `8730629415`), telling that `0` corresponds to `8`, `1` to `7`, `2` to `3`,… `9` to `5`; rather than 20 digits.

In this table of $2^{16}$ values, there are never two identical values. That makes it slightly compressible, down to $\log_2((2^{16})!)$ bit, a 9% saving.

Such a table needs not cover all plaintext/ciphertext pairs to be useful. A much smaller table can allow some attack. For example, a table with $2^8$ entries instead of $2^{16}$ allows decryption of about one block out of $2^8$.

Comment: I think i still cant get it why he multiplied 2^16 by 16 and didn't just add 2^16(those of the plaintext possibilities ) to  the block cipher possibilities .

Comment: @Khaled Gaber: see update.

Comment: thanks's for the update got it now